# Call @api on header of function

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

So, I'm working on this object where he inherits from another object
ODOO v8

```
class a(models.Model):
_inherit = 'my.inherit.object'

@api.multi
def _default_group(self):
    domain = {'group_id': [('id', 'in', False)]}
    user_c = self.env['timetable'].search([
        # ('company_id', '=', self.env.user.company_id.id),
        ('year_id', '=', self.year_id),
        ('user_id', '=', self.user_id.id), ])
    if not teacher:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(_("you haven't access, sorry so contact your administrator"))

    groups = []
    for line_groups in user_c:
        if line_groups.cd_id == self.cd_id:
            groups.append(line_groups.group_id.id)
        domain['group_id'] = [('id', 'in', groups)]


    return {'domain': domain}
```

so when I try to start this test code 
he shows me this error

```
Expected singleton: my.inherit.object ('lang', 'tz', 'params', 'uid', 'active_model')
```

What can I do to fix that, all fields are working and also the treatment is working fine, but it stops and shows me an error.

Comment: How are you calling that method `_default_group`. For what it's intended for?

Answer (score 1):

`self.ensure_one` is made to ensure that only one record is being passed on. It checks that the current record is a singleton (so just one record, not multiple records).

If self would contain multiple records the system would throw up an error.

You may try with following code:

```
@api.multi
def _default_group(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    # your logic start from here
```

Comment: is the same thing he still shows me the error  singleton

Comment: I have written a blog for same error. So it might be helpful for future debugging https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.com/2017/02/valueerror-expected-singleton-in-odoo.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for line_groups in user_c:
    for rec in self:
        if line_groups.cd_id == rec.cd_id:
            groups.append(line_groups.group_id.id)
    domain['group_id'] = [('id', 'in', groups)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method `_default_group` is used as default method - getting default values for a field - `self` is an empty recordset. But you're using `self` as singleton for example in `('year_id', '=', self.year_id)`. That won't work. To get values like year or whatever in default value methods, you will have to find a way around `self`.